# Android - Loop to collect all editText values

Tags: android, loops, android-edittext, findviewbyid

I have around 50 EditText fields and I want to get their values using a loop. Getting the values individually as below works fine:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.clear(); //not sure if this is required

    final EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1Value);
    String T1 = t1.getText().toString();
    editor.putstring("text1",T1);

    final EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2Value);
    String T2 = t2.getText().toString();
    editor.putstring("text2", T2);

   ................................ and so on till EditText t50.
```

I have tried achieving this through the loop below but couldn't get it to work.

```
       for(int x=1; x<50; x++) 
    {
        EditText et[x] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text[x]Value);
        String t[x] = et[x].getText().toString();
        String Ref = "text" + x;
        editor.putString(Ref, t[x]);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah thanks mate. Still not exactly at a working state yet though.

Comment: dont forget to `commit` or `apply` the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this by creating an array of the ids of the textview and looping through the array.
Try this:

```js
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.text1Value,R.id.text2Value,R.id.text3Value};//and so on

int i =1;
for(int id : ids){
    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(id);
    String Ref = "text" + i;
    editor.putString(Ref, t.getText().toString());
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you have all of these EditTexts inside a Layout called `ll` (should work for structures other than `Layout` too, such as a ViewGroup etc.):

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (ll.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
        EditText et = (EditText)ll.getChildAt(i);
        values.add(et.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

My Android is a little rusty so apologies if there is something wrong with that, but should give you the general idea anyway

Answer (score 0):

```js
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.text1Value,R.id.text2Value,R.id.text3Value};//and so on

int i =1;
for(int id : ids){
    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(id);
    String Ref = "text" + i;
    editor.putString(Ref, t.getText().toString());
  i++;
}
```

```
private void clearScreen() {
    int[] _ids = null;

    _ids = new int[]{R.id.etIdTAtividade, R.id.etNomeTAtividade, R.id.etNmAtividade};

    for (int i = 0; i < (_ids.length); i++) {
        EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(_ids[i]);
        t.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please could you add a description to this answer to tell the op how your solution works?